# How to commit my files in a git bare repo

Tags: git, repository

So I'm trying to learn git and I'm trying to make a git repo on my Debian virtual machine and play around with some files in order to learn the git commands. I've installed git core files, then I did the steps from [this tutorial](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux)

So i created the git user, created a /home/git/mydir.git and in it I executed
git --bare init

This is the step I'm stuck at. From what I've read so far, I need to go in the folder where my project files are at, and run:

git remote add central git@debianvm:myrepo.git

to add a central repo, but it doesn't work, it says not a git repository.
What am I missing? are there any steps or something that I need to perform? I'm a little confused about git bare repo and central repo concepts. Any advices or links on starting with git repositories would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `git clone git@debianvm:myrepo.git`. It will create local repo for you.